# zsh, oh-my-zsh, change current directory color

Tags: zsh, colors, theme, oh-my-zsh

I've installed oh-my-zsh withe the "pure" theme (https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure) and the current directory is now being shown at the prompt. The problem is that it's shown in a dark blue color and it's hard to distingush from the black background (the problem also occurs without the pure theme). I've modified the LSCOLORS but this doesn't work as only changes the output of the ls command.

[image]

How can I change it?

Comment: Edit the PROMPT variable.

Comment: @jasonwryan The prompt variable only has %(?.%F{magenta}.%F{red})${PURE_PROMPT_SYMBOL:-❯}%f. It seems like it is hardcoded, TT: 
https://github.com/wayneashleyberry/zshrc/blob/f6268c31475120f765eb35a7058ddb9aa098d93c/.zsh/pure.zsh#L137

Comment: +1 for the poetic title

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution but it is not what I expected. In the "pure" library what I was trying to change was the *preprompt*. See [this line](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/blob/291574e652c18f3513524be88913a96038e93e19/pure.zsh#L123). I wondered then why there isn't a config variable to change that and found this [issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/issues/126) saying that they don't want to introduce color config as it is an opinionated theme, so color configuration is not going to happen. The solution is then to fork the pure repository and change the color according to [zsh colors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Colors).